# Cocoa: Getting Mime Type of a url?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, mime-types

I would like to get the Mime Type of a url synchronously. I don't want to use NSURLConnection. 
Just something like:

> NSString *theMimeType = [self getMimeTypeFromURL:theURL];

Any ideas?

Comment: Synchronous network operations are evil. And with evil I mean something like a mass murderer who pushes little kids from a cliff into an ocean full of sharks while raping their mothers and burning buildings down.

Comment: @JustSid so every thread created by an NSURLConnection is a mass murderer who pushes little kids from a cliff into an ocean full of sharks while raping their mothers and burning buildings down?

Comment: @Radek S: Uhm, NSURLConnection doesn't spawn a thread, it works asynchronously in the current run loop and thus not only saves you the overhead of spawning a thread, but also saves you from the evil mass murderer ;)

Comment: @JustSid that's just sid. I mean: whoops I didn't know.

Comment: I know it's not that good, but still I need it. I simply would like to know the mime type of every page I load in the UIWebView so I want to put it in shouldStartLoadWithRequest...

Comment: @Alex1987: Wait, you want to perform the request twice just to get the mime type?! "Not that good" is a pretty harmless description. Just load the request once and pass the data to the UIWebView if you need the mime type so desperate before the UIWebView should display something.

Answer (score 9):

There is absolutely no reason ***not*** to use asynchronous requests.

Use `NSURLConnection`'s delegate approach.

```
NSString        *url  = ...;
NSURLRequest    *req  = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
[conn start];
```

Somewhere else in your `@implementation`:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

   NSString *mime = [response MIMEType];
   //do something with mime
}
```

Comment: Synchronous requests are "easier" in that they isolate the post-request processing logic to the same area of code where the request was sent off in the first place. Sadly, I feel like this is one reason why people still use synchronous requests. :-\

Comment: @LucasTizma I agree with you 100%.